# how to store large amount of photos and videos uploaded by user?

Tags: mysql, facebook, rdbms, flickr

On you tube,facebook,flicker millions of photos and videos are

uploaded by users so how they manage all such large uploads.i know that they have large space

on their servers but i just want to ask that which technique they are using to store this

kind of huge data?

And also please suggest me to best way to get this kind of large uploads from user.

Thanks

Comment: -1 Your question is way, way too general. Try to be much more specific and also define what you know; for example 'technique to store huge data' is called writing data to storage device. But I doubt that this answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my knowledge, facebook has no less than thirty thousand servers there with them and expanding, so big data, big requirements and expenditure.

The best way to store those in my view is to simply upload photos and videos to specific ***folders*** and simply save the ***file names*** in the corresponding tables rather than photos and videos themselves in blob format.

Answer (score 6):

Best get it straight from the horse's mouth:

- http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919
- http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/uploads/flickr_php.pdf

Given that the flickr presentation is quite dated (still talks about PHP4), you'll probably want to check out the flickr developers' blog, which has a ton of inside baseball on developing high scalability applications with large data storage needs:
http://code.flickr.com/blog/2010/02/